# Changing a column from NULL to NOT NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to change a column from NULL to NOT NULL in SQL Server 2014. This is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE purchase_order_line ALTER COLUMN pol_sl_id INT NOT NULL
```

However, I am prevented from doing so by the following error message:

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The index 'idx_pol_33' is dependent on column 'pol_sl_id'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN pol_sl_id failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

I can confirm that there are no NULL values in this column.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have to drop all the indexes and constraints (and perhaps some other dependencies) that reference this column before you run this - and then add them all back once you successfully run your alter statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your errors are straightforward. You have to drop and recreate indexes and statistics.

Like:

```
DROP STATISTICS table.statistics_name | view.statistics_name [ ,...n ]
DROP INDEX <table_name>.<index_name>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this was the correct answer. In order to help anyone else who has this difficulty, I simply used SQL Server's "Drop and Create to - New File" Functionality to ensure that all indexes were dropped and recreated identically.